# SSMA for Oracle to SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, sql-server-2008-r2, database-migration

For some reasons, I need to migrate **Oracle 11g DB** to **SQL Server 2008 R2**.
I have downloaded SSMA v7.11  and tried to migrate, but it can migrate only as SQL Server 2012 database.

Are there any other tools like SSMA or how to download old versions of SSMA that can migrate to SQL Server 2008 R2 as well?

Comment: SQL Server 208 R2 [falls out of support](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2008) in July of 2019. You're not buying much time with that migration. SQL Server 2012 is already on Extended Support. You should really consider moving to a currently supported product.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL server Management Studio "Import and Export Wizard"

right click on target SQL-server DB -> Tasks -> Import data.

Then follow the wizard steps